# Are Matt LeBlanc's financial troubles a caricature of Nicolas Cage?

Tags: episodes-2011

In the Showtime/BBC series *Episodes*, Matt LeBlanc plays himself. In the latest season (Season 4), a key plot point involves Matt facing financial problems along with overdue taxes.

I couldn't help but notice the similarity between the plot and the real-life problems of Nicolas Cage. Both involve a plane, a car collection, real estate and even a dinosaur egg (Cage purchased a dinosaur skull) bought by the actors insensibly. Both also involve a spat with the financial manager of the actor. (EDIT: Although, in the show, LeBlanc blames his manager after he dies)

However, I haven't read any reviews or articles pointing out these similarities.

Is this a coincidence? Or are the writers actively satirizing Cage's life through the fictional Matt LeBlanc

Comment: Without a canonical answer from the writers, which probably won't come because of potential legal issues since this *wouldn't* be satirical, I don't think you're gonna ever know the answer to this.

Comment: He doesn't have a spat with his "money guy" - the money guy dies, revealing the scope of the cheating he was doing.

Comment: @KateGregory: I'm aware of it. Just trying to phrase it so it's common to both cases. Cage's agent, didn't die, I think :)

Comment: I think you mean 'foolishly' rather than 'insensibly'.